# MariaDB shell not displaying unicode characters

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8, mariadb

I can't seem to get the MariaDB shell to display unicode characters properly:

```
$ mysql -u root --default-character-set=utf8mb4 -e "SELECT 'ф'"
+---+
| ? |
+---+
| ? |
+---+
```

Using `char` instead of the character:

```
$ mysql -u root --default-character-set=utf8mb4 -e "SELECT char( 208,164 USING utf8 );"
+----------------------------+
| char( 208,164 USING utf8 ) |
+----------------------------+
| ðñ                          |
+----------------------------+
```

Running the same command from the windows subsystem for linux:

```
joaqu@BB:~$ mysql -h 172.19.192.1 -u linux -p -e "SELECT char( 208,164 USING utf8 );"
+----------------------------+
| char( 208,164 USING utf8 ) |
+----------------------------+
| Ф                          |
+----------------------------+
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Well: which encoding does your shell use to send `ф` to a program? A more appropriate SQL to test would be `SELECT char( 208,164 USING utf8 );` as that only needs ASCII for interpretation.

Comment: Great question thanks! Sending `char` doesn't seem to help - what does this mean? Using the linux subsystem, your statement prints out `ф` correctly.

Comment: If you're not directly operating that OS then make sure other layers on top (remote connection, terminals, etc...) are not messing up the encodings while MySQL/MariaDB themselves behave correctly. Check [How can I enable UTF-8 support in the Linux console?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/303712)

Comment: Weirdly, linux (running in the windows subsystem) is working, but windows itself is not. I can't understand why `SELECT char` would be different depending on whether the client is connecting from Windows or Linux...!

Comment: As a side question, how did you find out the char values for `ф`?

Comment: Most letters have [their own Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ф), which in turn list their Unicode codepoint and mostly also its UTF-8 encoding. Or searching in a list of all codepoints, i.e. https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=880&utf8=dec